# Why did Poppy ask Angel to kill his friend Charles, in the beginning of the movie?

Tags: kingsman-the-golden-circle

Did Charles actually do something to deserve Poppy’s punishment, or was it just a loyalty test for the new recruit, Angel?

Maybe Charles did wrong by telling Angel about the Golden Circle?

Comment: She didn't, she told that to Angel later in the movie. But I think she never gave a reason to kill Charles (the bald guy at the begining of the movie).

Comment: From "fan subtitles" (found https://subscene.com/subtitles/kingsman-the-golden-circle/english/1675244), "Your old pal, Charles, has messed up. That's all I'm gonna tell you,'cause that's all you need to know." which I guess are quite near what it's said in the movie.

Comment: Wow. I remembered that part pretty clearly.. I guess not.

Comment: I’m not expecting people to remember it, but they can review the scene, that is why I asked, because it’s not an obvious answer.

Comment: Because he messed up something and Poppy wasn't happy about it..